# Dynamic model creation for odata entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, odata, wcf-data-services

I need to know how to customise OData (web api) so that when a user requests an entity, he is shown only the properties on that entity. Suppose

### CarModel

RecordId

Make

Model

Cost

CostToMake

DateMade

Further suppose UserA and UserB. UserA can see RecordId, Make, Model, Cost however, UserB can see RecordId, Model, CostToMake

I have tried several solutions on the web..

1) https://github.com/OData/ODataSamples/blob/master/WebApi/v4/DynamicEdmModelCreation/DynamicEdmModelCreation -- problem with this is that it does generate the model at run time but it does not support odata query and I am not sure how to configure it to support odata query ( I have tried placing EnableQuery attribute on the HandleAllControll Get method to no success)

2) https://github.com/OData/ODataSamples/tree/master/WebApi/v4/ODataUntypedSample/ODataUntypedSample
I have tried this one as well, there are two problems with this one, it builds model at service startup therefore I end up with nulls or default values for unaccessable values. Secondly, it also does not support query.. and it has a bug on "/odata/Products?$filter=Id eq 1", this query returns full product list.